# Messed up git tree, how to fix?

Tags: git

I'm new to using Git and I thought I had a decent grasp of it until today. I made some changes today that I didn't like and wanted to basically wipe all of todays changes away and go back to my last commit where I began this morning. 3 reverts later and other random commands I found on Stack Overflow issues and my git tree is screwed up.

I want to make my local repo the same as whats live on heroku, so 28924e8. How do I get rid of the rest of it?

[image: Picture of git tree:]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can completely remove/forget changes with the `reset` subcommand. In your case, do `git reset --hard 28924e8`. This will remove all commits and working copy changes (though not untracked files) and reset you back to a clean copy of 28924e8. (Whichever branch you're on when you do this will be the one you reset, so you may want to do `git checkout master` first. Also, you can use `git branch -D` to nuke any branches you don't want afterwards.)

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. And just so I dont ruin anything else.. I'd like 1ffd9a8, f2ee21e, and 30c9b98 to be removed. What would I do to get rid of those?

Comment: So im typing "git branch -D 1ffd9a8" and its telling me I need a branch name. "git branch -D refs/stash" doesnt work either

Comment: He was referring to the `git reset --hard 28924e8`.

Comment: the git reset --hard command worked so that my local repo is how it was this morning, so thats good. though when i use git log --graph --oneline --all to check my git tree, its still the same as in the above picture. edit: there is one difference. it now says HEAD -> on 28924e8

Comment: @user601206 `refs/stash` is special. To get rid of it, do `git stash clear`.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Tree looks good now. You saved me a lot of stress